# When will Sencha Touch 2.0 go to general availability?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Current release is 1.1, and 2.0 is in developer preview. When is it expected to be GA.

Comment: I think you must search and ask in Sencha's forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from a comment on this page: http://www.sencha.com/learn/upgrading-to-sencha-touch-2-pr2

> @Mike, our goal is to release Touch 2 Beta by early next year or
>   sooner.  We will review our final release/GA date based on the
>   feedback we get from the beta.